# GAM command not running as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-gsuite

I'm in the process of making changes to groups, when testing this against 1 group I can confirm this works but now I'm attempting to run this against a .csv which contains a list of all groups using the following.

```
gam csv mygroup.csv  | gam update group mygroup.csv who_can_view_group all_members_can_view
```

This returns an error so I went on to try the next

```
gam csv mygroup.csv |  gam update group ~Email who_can_view_group all_members_can_view
```

This also does not work, what am I doing wrong?

The error message:

> zsh: no such user or named directory: Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an OS-specific issue. I'm using mac which means you need to encase Email with "

```
gam csv mygroups.csv gam update group "~Email" who_can_view_group all_members_can_view
```

When running the above this works as expected